# Getting error : 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' while loading the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My CNN model is trained and saved successfully but during loading the model in prediction using load model, I am getting this attribute error. What does it say and how to resolve it? Can anyone help with that?
Code:

```
sm = tf.keras.models.load_model("CNN_full_dataset.h5")
image = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Dataset\Validation\ValidationData_Brightness_Final\Kaa\image_14022021_234339.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
image = cv2.resize(image,(32,32))
test_image = np.expand_dims(image,2)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image,0)
result = sm.predict(test_image)
label = classes[np.argmax(result)]
label
cv2.imshow("image",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**
This is the Treceback:
**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-cc93ae8cc6aa> in <module>
----> 1 sm = tf.keras.models.load_model("CNN_full_dataset.h5")
      2 image = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Dataset\Validation\ValidationData_Brightness_Final\Kaa\image_14022021_234339.jpg",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
      3 image = cv2.resize(image,(32,32))
      4 test_image = np.expand_dims(image,2)
      5 test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image,0)

~\Anaconda3\envs\OCR_ENV\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\save.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    144       h5py is not None and (
    145           isinstance(filepath, h5py.File) or h5py.is_hdf5(filepath))):
--> 146     return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    147 
    148   if isinstance(filepath, six.string_types):

~\Anaconda3\envs\OCR_ENV\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\saving\hdf5_format.py in load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    208     if model_config is None:
    209       raise ValueError('No model found in config file.')
--> 210     model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
    211     model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config,
    212                                                custom_objects=custom_objects)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: Try using `sm = tf.keras.models.load_model(b"CNN_full_dataset.h5")` instead of `sm = tf.keras.models.load_model("CNN_full_dataset.h5")`

Comment: If that doesn't help, it's probably a bug in Tensorflow. Then, the last thing you could try is to update Tensorflow with `python -m pip install -U tensorflow` (you may have to replace `python` with `py` or `python.exe` or `py.exe`).

Comment: You are trying to decode an object that is already decoded.Check your input type. Thanks!